# Retrieving variables from HTML with JSON data contained in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a simple HTML file that contains data I'm trying to scrape out so that I can work with the variables.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class ="pane">
            <div class ="chart">
                <h1 style='float: left;'>Summary</h1>
                <div style='clear: both;'></div>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="protovis/protovis-d3.2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript+protovis">var data = [
                {"label":"A (2)", 'complete': 2.0, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":" B (8)", 'complete': 8, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":"C (10)", 'complete': 10, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":"D (18)", 'complete': 18.0, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":"E (21)", 'complete': 21, 'pending': 0.0}
                ];
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Using PHP, I'm trying to parse the data contained on this HTML in to variables.  I.E.: `$A = 2`, `$B = 8`, `$C = 10`, `$D = 18`, `$E = 21`.

So far, I've been trying to use the simple_html_dom.php library to read the data, but I haven't been able to retrieve the contents of the JSON contained within the JavaScript above.

How can I pull `"label":"A (2)"` out of the HTML above so that I can access the value (in this case 2) as a PHP variable?

Comment: i don't understand your question. PHP is server based, so you have to send any data you want to use in PHP to your server (via Ajax)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the question.  I'm currently reading the HTML file above using simple_html_dom.php and $html = file_get_html('status.html') and trying to read the contents of the file that way.  However, I'm not entirely sure if I'm headed down the right path.

Comment: what @messerbill said. and what are you trying to do with the data after you got it in PHP? do you want to display it on the same html page? - if so then you can easily manipulate your DOM with (for example) jQuery and don't need PHP at all.

Comment: is there a special event before the data should be submitted to the server?

Comment: Thanks @low_rents.  I need to add two of the values together and output all of these variables to via a curl post to update a remote page.  I have the curl update working nicely, I'm just having trouble obtaining the data that I need to relay.

Comment: @messerbill no, no special event... just trying to read the html file, and work with the values as variables.  I thought this would be easier than it is obviously.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: @JimmyPinno another problem might be, that your json is not valid (according to http://jsonlint.com/). you need to use double-quotes inside your json, even if some interpreters also allow single quotes - PHP's json_decode doesn't.

Comment: @JimmyPinno see my answer - i got it, using `file_get_contents()` and a "dirty" parsing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it with `file_get_contents()`.

**note:**
the parsing is really just a quick and dirty solution. it only works if you got only one `[` and one `]` in your file which have to mark your json-string. so if you need to use this on a lot of files, you should use another parsing method for sure.

1. read the html into a string:

`$html = file_get_contents("my_file.html");`

2. parse your html for the json-string (like noticed this is bad practice and just a quick&dirty solution for your exact problem):

`$json = substr($html, strpos($html, '[') , strpos($html, ']') - (strpos($html, '[')-1));`

3. replace singlequotes by doublequotes (since there need to be double-quotes so that the string is valid json):

`$json = str_replace("'", "\"", $json);`

4. use `json_decode` to convert your json to a php array. note: you need to set the 2nd parameter to `true` in order to use "associative mode":

`$my_array = json_decode($json, true);`

here you go, when you do `var_dump($my_array)` you see that everything is saved into the php array:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(5) "A (2)"
    ["complete"]=>
    float(2)
    ["pending"]=>
    float(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(6) " B (8)"
    ["complete"]=>
    int(8)
    ["pending"]=>
    float(0)
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank-you.  Specifically, the note about the json format being invalid helped me a lot.  Also nice to know that I don't need to use an external library to accomplish this.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to parse the `label` values inside `data` into variables using **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**.

Use one of the following methods to create a `DOM object`

```
// Create a DOM object from a string
$html = str_get_html('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');

// Create a DOM object from a URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Create a DOM object from a HTML file
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');
```

Which one you choose depends on your situation, since i don't know if your fetching from an `URL` or a file `file` or even a `string`, i thought i list them all. But it really does not matter.

Now if you have your `DOM object` set up do the following.

```
// save the second occurrence of script tag in $ret.
$ret = $html->find('script', 1);

// use preg_match_all to find what you are looing for,
// you might want to adjust the regex to fit your needs, but this will work for now.
preg_match_all("/\"label\"\s*:\s*([^}]+)/", $ret, $out);

// know loop over matched result and adjust the string to be parsed to a variable.
foreach($out[1] as $key => $value) {
    $out[1][$key] = str_replace([' ','(',')','"'],['','=','',''] , substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ',')));
    parse_str($out[1][$key]);
}

// now you can do:
print_r($A); // 2
print_r($B); // 8
print_r($C); // 10
print_r($D); // 18
print_r($E); // 21
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this one

```
var data = [
                {"label":"A (2)", 'complete': 2.0, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":" B (8)", 'complete': 8, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":"C (10)", 'complete': 10, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":"D (18)", 'complete': 18.0, 'pending': 0.0}
                ,{"label":"E (21)", 'complete': 21, 'pending': 0.0}
                ];

output

for(var i =0; i <= data.length; i++){
    alert(data[i]['label']);
    }
```